# Strange behaviour for IOS 6 rotation

Tags: ios6, uinavigationcontroller, rotation, xcode4.5, autorotate

I have search the net and in the forum for two weeks. I couldn't find anything like my problem.
I have an app build on the IOS 3 and in time I made it compatible with all IOS versions.
All the app is in portrait mode and I only have one screen (a chart) which is in landscape mode. Until IOS 5 and IOS 5 also I get the beautiful rect with black edges when rotating.
On IOS 6 I see that after I rotate I get the chart Nib is being presented from the top right corner. (I can't post an image or a video to demonstrate it as it has a logo and I'm not sure it's allowed.

I am using setRootViewController at the beginning.

I attached a sketch to demonstrate.[image]

How can I retrieve the right animation?

Comment: any news to this one?

Comment: No. I had to design the architecture again, then it works.